# Vuex: How to change store state from a service script file state is undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm trying to change a `loggedIn` state in `$store` to true, during signup. However I get

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined
```

error on line

```js
updateLoggedIn(value)  {
        this.$store.state.loggedIn = value;
    },
```

in **AuthenticationService.js**.

`./store/index.js`:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
    },
    state:  {
        token: '',
        user: null,
        loggedIn: false
    },
...
```

**SignupPage.vue**:

```js
...
  methods:  {
    async register(formData) {
      const username = formData.get("Username");
      const email = formData.get("Email");
      const password = formData.get("Password");

      console.log(username);
      console.log(email);
      console.log(password);

      console.log("register()")
      const response = AuthenticationService.register({
        email: email,
        username: username,
        password: password
      }).then((response) => {
        console.log(response)
        console.log(this.$store)
        this.$router.push({
          name: 'ha'
        })
      },
      error =>  {
        console.log("ERROR! signup");
        console.log(error);
      });
    }
  }
...
```

**AuthenticationService.vue**:

```js
import api from './api'

const  registeredUsers = []

export default  {
    updateLoggedIn(value)  {
        this.$store.state.loggedIn = value;
    },
    register ( credentials)  {
        registeredUsers.push(credentials);
        registeredUsers.push("nooo")
        console.log(registeredUsers)
        return api().post('register', credentials).then(
            response =>  {
               /* commit("updateLoggedInt", true);*/
                this.updateLoggedIn(true);
               /* this.$store.state.status.registerSuccess = false;*/
                console.log(this.$store);
                return Promise.resolve(response);
            },
            error =>  {
                this.$store.state.status.loggedIn = false;
                return Promise.reject(error);
            }
        )
    },
...
```

**api.js**:

```js
import axios from 'axios'
import store from '../../src/store'

export default()  =>  {
    return axios.create({
        baseURL: 'http://localhost:8081',
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${store.state.token}`
        }
    })
};
```

**EDIT**:

Still get the problem:

[image]

on line 8

```js
import api from './api'

const  registeredUsers = []
let ref = this

export default  {
    updateLoggedIn(value)  {
        ref.$store.state.loggedIn = value;
    },
...
```

Comment: It sounds like your store instance wasn't passed to Vue. Can you show your init code that bootstraps Vue?

Comment: @tony19, Thanks I solved it. I just imported store directly instead of trying to use `this`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it.

I added this import to `AuthenticationService.js`:

```
import store from '../../src/store/index'
```

and used the store object like this:

```js
    updateLoggedIn(value)  {
        store.state.loggedIn = value;
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

your first mistake is **changing state without mutation**.

your second mistake is the **call method from another component**.

after resolve this mistakes:

I think the reason for $store is not defined is **this** keyword.

in the first line of the register add this variable:

```
let ref = this
```

then in request callback:

```
console.log(ref.$store)
```

you can also use **bind(this)** to request callback function

Comment: It's the same problem. unfortunatelly